# NoClassDefFound error happens when try call class from jar library after put into my project

Tags: java, android, maven, jar

There are 2 projects : `My project` and `Library project`.

I already export [Android library project to jar file successfully, built from `aar` to `jar`](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/) in Android studio.

So now, I put that `jar` into the `my project` to allow to use it as library.

After clean & sync gradle successfully. `My project` can understand class in `jar` library correct.

But after launched, it still get crashes and get below exception related to `jar library`,

I don't know why,

People who know, Please tell me how to fix,

Thank you,

p/s : Actually, I try to publish the jar library to maven, so I need test before publish.

If I not declare activity `CustomCamera` and `CustomGallery`, I will get crash and get exception not declare activity in manifest.xml yet.

**Exception**

```
 Process: mirrortowers.beautiful_bag.android.custom_camera.custom_gallery,    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lmirrortowers/custom_camera_gallery_library/R$layout;
E/AndroidRuntime:     at ui.activity.custom.camera.CustomCamera.onCreate(CustomCamera.java:93)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mirrortowers.custom_camera_gallery_library.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mirrortowers.beautiful_bag.android.custom_camera.custom_gallery-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at ui.activity.custom.camera.CustomCamera.onCreate(CustomCamera.java:93) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
E/AndroidRuntime:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mirrortowers.custom_camera_gallery_library.R$layout
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime:           ... 15 more
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**Project structure**

Try put into `libs` folder and add it as library -> not works.

[image]

Try put into `app` folder and add it as library -> not works.

[image]

**Manifest.xml in Jar library**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mirrortowers.custom_camera_gallery_library">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- custom camera and gallery-->
        <activity
            android:name="ui.activity.custom.camera.CustomCamera"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="ui.activity.custom.gallery.CustomGallery" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Manifest.xml in my project**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mirrortowers.beautiful_bag.android.custom_camera.custom_gallery">

<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DonateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme" />

    <!-- custom camera and gallery-->
    <activity
        android:name="ui.activity.custom.camera.CustomCamera"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity android:name="ui.activity.custom.gallery.CustomGallery" />

</application>
```

**app.build.gradle in jar library**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.10'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}

// ext is a gradle closure allowing the declaration of global properties
ext {
PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'android.mirrortowers'
PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'custom_camera_gallery'
PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0.0'
}

def groupId = project.PUBLISH_GROUP_ID
def artifactId = project.PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID
def version = project.PUBLISH_VERSION

def localReleaseDest = "${buildDir}/release/${version}"


uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    pom.groupId = groupId
    pom.artifactId = artifactId
    pom.version = version
    // Add other pom properties here if you want (developer details / licenses)
    repository(url: "file://${localReleaseDest}")
}
}

task zipRelease(type: Zip) {
from localReleaseDest
destinationDir buildDir
archiveName "release-${version}.zip"
}

task generateRelease << {
println "Release ${version} can be found at ${localReleaseDest}/"
println "Release ${version} zipped can be found ${buildDir}/release-${version}.zip"
}

generateRelease.dependsOn(uploadArchives)
generateRelease.dependsOn(zipRelease)
```

**app.build.gradle in my project**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile files('src/main/libs/custom_camera_gallery_library.jar')
}
```

Comment: cutom camera module is missing

Comment: @war_Hero : You checked my project structure? You can see package camera module not missing. How to fix it?

Comment: go to files-->project structure-->app-->dependencies check if u can see there if not tell me

Comment: @war_Hero : Please check again image. Actually I can call & integrate class from Jar library in My project.

Comment: Does your library have resources? If so, building it as a jar is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, it has resource. Because I want publish jar to maven center. So I did it. Do you recommend me the other way? Thank you.

Comment: You can publish directly the aar.

Comment: @Henry I mean before I publish aar directly to maven center, I need test. So this question related to testing. I tested with the way : Use library project as module and put into my project, it worked already. So I want test with case jar library to make sure everything is OK.